# How to add items to an ObservableCollection based on the month?

Tags: xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` for storing the month events. I am adding the month events like below: where `AllItems` is my `ObservableCollection`.

```
AllItems = new ObservableCollection<EventsHB>();

        EventsHB januvaryGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "January" };
        EventsHB februvaryGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "February" };
        EventsHB marchGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "March" };
        EventsHB aprilGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "April" };
        EventsHB mayGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "May" };
        EventsHB juneGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "June" };
        EventsHB julyGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "July" };
        EventsHB augustGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "August" };
        EventsHB septemberGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "September" };
        EventsHB octoberGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "October" };
        EventsHB novemberGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "November" };
        EventsHB decemberGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "December" };

        foreach (var item in allItem)
        {
            EventsHBTwo hb = item;
            if (hb.month == "January")
            {
                januvaryGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "February")
            {
                februvaryGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "March")
            {
                marchGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "April")
            {
                aprilGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "May")
            {
                mayGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "June")
            {
                juneGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "July")
            {
                julyGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "June")
            {
                juneGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "July")
            {
                julyGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "August")
            {
                augustGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "September")
            {
                septemberGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "October")
            {
                octoberGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "November")
            {
                novemberGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "December")
            {
                decemberGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
        }
 try
        {
            List<EventsHB> MonthsData = new List<EventsHB>() { null, januvaryGroup, februvaryGroup, marchGroup, aprilGroup, marchGroup, juneGroup, julyGroup, augustGroup, septemberGroup, octoberGroup, novemberGroup, decemberGroup };
            int currentMonth = 12;
            while (AllItems.Count < 12)
            {
                AllItems.Add(MonthsData[currentMonth]);
                currentMonth++;
                if (currentMonth == 13)
                    currentMonth = 1;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Event Exception:>>"+e);
        }
```

Is it possible to add the events based on the month? If the current month is `August` I need to add the `august` events to the collection first. Then `September` to `July`. It is possible to do without using 12 if conditions?

Comment: I will share with you the logic soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this logic :- I have build the logic using Strings you need to modify using your model class.
    MonthsData will be your data :- januvaryGroup, februvaryGroup, etc. You need to add an empty group before that.

```
List<string> MonthsData = new List<string>() { "", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string>());
while(list.Count < 12)
{
     list.Add(MonthsData[currentMonth]);
     currentMonth++;
     if (currentMonth == 13)
          currentMonth = 1;
}
```

Let me know if you have queries.

Comment: I have edited the question with more details, can you please have a look

Comment: Yes I will send you updated logic. Kindly give me sometime.

Comment: Kindly look at the change. int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month; I missed on this, sorry my bad. Can you please update your code and try and run.

Comment: I got an exception: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: SmartWCM.Model.EventsHB

Comment: I can share you a sample project, can you help if I share a sample?

Comment: Yes sure, kindly share a sample project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198706/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-nikhil).